# jQuery submit form and then disable all 'input[type="submit"]' to prevent duplicate submissions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got an odd issue that the common solutions won't seem to fix. I get some funky behavior when a user clicks an html based form which is submitted if they click 'save', 'previous' or 'next'.

```
<div class="form-tab-nav form-tab-nav-bottom">
  <input id="tab" name="tab" tabindex="25" type="hidden" value="3">
  <input name="commit" tabindex="26" type="submit" value="Save">
    <input id="prev_commit_bottom" name="prev_commit[bottom]" tabindex="27" type="submit" value="<< Prev">
  <input class="orange" id="next_commit_bottom" name="next_commit[bottom]" tabindex="28" type="submit" value="Next >>">
</div>
```

Using jQuery 1.6.1:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

This will disable the button so that a second post request isn't allowed, but it disables the redirect. That is clicking 'previous' or 'next' will behave the same as clicking 'save'.

Comment: Because you are disabling the form before it submits, nothing will happen.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jxv7un8c/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate the help from everyone, but this is the solution that fixed our double submit problems:

```
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    if ($form.data('submitted') === true) {
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $form.data('submitted', true);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are disabling the form before it submits, nothing will happen. You would have to set a timeout to allow the submission to happen.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var after = $.proxy(function () {
        $(this).find("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled',true);
    },this);
    window.setTimeout(after,50);
});
```

or

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var elems = $(this).find("input[type='submit']");
    var after = function () {
        elems.prop('disabled',true);
    };
    window.setTimeout(after,50);
});
```

Comment: I have a page that disables the submit button with plain Javascript, not jQuery, and it works just fine. Is it different when using jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript...so it probably does the same thing under the covers.

Comment: That's my point. When I do it, it doesn't prevent the form from submitting. Why would the timer be needed with jQuery?

Comment: I was kind of thinking this was the problem, but I feel like there's got to be a better solution than using a setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  this line

```
<input id="prev_commit_bottom" name="prev_commit[bottom]" tabindex="27" type="submit" value="<< Prev">
```

try this

```
<input id="prev_commit_bottom" name="prev_commit[bottom]" tabindex="27" type="submit" value="&lt;&lt; Prev">
```